# Extra meta fields in posts table that loads my db

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

A simple woocommerce store, when exporting a csv products catalog, I noticed my sheet contains **thousands** of extra fields that had no value, I have no clue where did it all came from and cannot associate it with any plugin that I'm using at the moment. for example:

- meta:158275-wpfoof-google

  meta:157909-wpfoof-identifier_exists

  meta:157911-wpfoof-adsensecustom

Wondering how can I safely get rid of this additional custom fields.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

These entries are coming from this plugin:

https://www.pixelyoursite.com/plugins/product-catalog-feed-for-woocommerce

Haven't figured out how to disable that in the plugin settings, but I suspect you could remove them without any issues.